# Aube et aurore, crépuscule et ?

Tags: vocabulaire, indications-de-temps

On sait que l'aube précède l'aurore, au moins dans l'usage soigné.  Au soir le crépuscule correspond à l'aube, y a-t-il un terme désignant le moment correspondant à l'aurore?

Comment: Entre chien et loup?

Comment: A noter : il me semble que le crépuscule peut également faire référence au matin, au moment précédant immédiatement l'aube.

Comment: @RomainVALERI, un des sens (que je crois plutôt technique utilisé en astronomie) de crépuscule est la lumière du soleil sous l'horizon, et dans ce sens il peut être utilisé pour désigner la lumière de l'aube.

Answer (score 11):

Je dirais [couchant](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/couchant) (m) - Le soleil qui se couche; l'aspect et la luminosité du soleil et du ciel au moment du coucher du soleil (cit. TLFi). Ou [tombée de la nuit](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/tomb%C3%A9e_de_la_nuit), coucher de soleil ?

**EDIT**: Un peu de lexique crépusculaire (TLFi):

> **crépuscule** - Lumière faible et incertaine qui subsiste après le coucher du soleil avant que la nuit ne soit complètement tombée; moment correspondant de la journée.
>
> **aurore** - Moment qui suit l'aube et précède immédiatement le lever du soleil, où l'horizon présente des lueurs brillantes et rosées
>
> **aube** - Moment qui précède l'aurore, où la lumière du soleil levant commence à blanchir l'horizon; point(e) du jour.
>
> Rem. **Oppos. aube/aurore.** Bon nombre d'écrivains confondent plus ou moins aurore avec aube, en partic. quand ils font suivre ce dernier d'adj. comme éblouissant, doré, etc. (cf. aube). Par ailleurs, les deux mots apparaissent quelquefois en coordination, ce qui confirme la difficulté de les distinguer : ,,Loin d'être une aube, une aurore, c'est le souvenir d'un triste chant de crépuscule`` (Barrès, La Colline inspirée, 1913, p. 204). Pourtant ils sont loin d'être synon., l'aube précède l'aurore; quand, p. méton., l'aube désigne les premières lueurs du jour, la coloration est blanchâtre, indécise, voilée. Au contraire l'aurore est brillante, éclatante, soit rosée, soit jaune doré. Ce sens de « lumière brillante et rosée » est au demeurant bien plus fréq. et net que celui de « moment qui suit l'aube », sens que les dict. omettent même de signaler, alors que certains d'entre eux (DG, Rob.) le mentionnent bien pour aube. Les teintes de l'aurore sont suffisamment précises pour donner lieu à un emploi comme adj. de couleur (contrairement à aube). Enfin, les accept. figurées, comparables à celles de aube, ne s'accompagnent pas cependant − ou rarement − de la même nuance d'insaisissable, d'impalpable; l'aube cherche à poindre, à naître; l'aurore éclate, illumine.

Ainsi, je peux faire une telle succession de ces mots:

- coucher du soleil > crépuscule > lever du soleil
- coucher du soleil > crépuscule > aube > aurore > lever du soleil (selon TLFi, pour les puristes)
- couchant (?) > coucher du soleil > crépuscule > aube > aurore > lever du soleil
- [avant-nuit](http://books.google.ru/books?id=j445yDsvJWkC&pg=PA314&dq=%22avant-nuit%22&hl=ru&sa=X&ei=vXooUvicLYjNtAbBuICoDg&ved=0CDsQ6AEwAjgU#v=onepage&q=%22avant-nuit%22&f=false) (très rare) (?) > coucher du soleil > crépuscule > aube > aurore > lever du soleil
- tombée de la nuit (?) > coucher du soleil > crépuscule > aube > aurore > lever du soleil

Encore une notion intéressante dans ce champs lexical c'est [heure bleue](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heure_bleue) considérée comme synonyme de *entre chien et loup*  et de *brunante*  selon wikipédia français. Je ne sais pas trop où je peux placer ces termes.

Selon TLFi, tous ces lexèmes sont synonymes: brune, brunante, entre chien et loup, tombée du jour, tombée de la nuit, crépuscule, heure bleue (cette dernière n'est pas dans le TLFi).

Donc, je crois qu'on peut jouer sur la différence *tombée du jour > tombée de la nuit* (?). Mais je ne suis pas sûr.

- tombée du jour (?) > tombée de la nuit (?) > couchant (?) > coucher du soleil > crépuscule > aube > aurore > lever du soleil

Si l'on parle d'astronomie, on distingue encore plusieurs types de crépuscules: civil, nautique (heure bleue), astronomique. Selon TLFi, ces crépuscules-là, on peut les employer aussi dans un contexte de  lever de soleil.

Donc, le concept astronomique c'est:

- coucher du soleil > crépuscule civil > crépuscule nautique (heure bleue) > crépuscule astronomique > lever du soleil

Pour avoir l'image intégrale on peut ajouter aussi [nuit noire](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/nuit_noire)

- coucher du soleil > crépuscule civil  > crépuscule nautique  > crépuscule astronomique > nuit noire > crépuscule astronomique > crépuscule nautique > crépuscule civil > lever du soleil

L’intégrale, avec les termes du lexique non-astronomique, vous pouvez la faire par vous-mêmes :-)

Comment: Oui, ponant ca va aussi, mais j'ai l'impression que c'est plutot vielli et un peu regional... Mais, peut-etre j'ai tort. Je considere ponant et couchant comme synonymes, mais ponant plus vielli.. (Pardon, j'ai un clavier sans accent)

Comment: Le _ponant_ est pour moi un synonyme d'Ouest, ou de couchant dans le sens de la direction du soleil qui se couche et pas la période.  Pour _couchant_ en tant que période, c'est pour moi le moment où le soleil est en train de disparaitre mais encore visible, je cherche le moment après, le soleil est sous l'horizon mais il fait encore clair (le crépuscule étant le moment où la lumière disparait).

Answer (score 5):

L'usage actuel fait précéder la nuit par le *crépuscule* (du latin crepusculum, de creperus "douteux").

Au XIII° siècle il était rattaché à l'*aube*, comme une lueur précédent le lever du soleil.

**Brune** : tombée de la nuit, soir.

> *[Ce](http://www.paroles-musique.com/paroles-Maxime_Le_Forestier-Leducation_Sentimentale-lyrics,p14658)* soir, *à la* brune, *nous irons, ma brune cueillir des serments
> ...
>  (Maxime Le Forestier : L’éducation sentimentale)*

Définitions extraites du petit Robert.

P.S. : S'il n'y avait pas la tautologie *ce soir/brune* la phrase serait incompréhensible : à *cette brune* est inaudible, indécodable, alors qu'*à ce soir* l'est, et *brune* précise ici le début de la soirée.

Le *soir* est ce qui existe entre le *crépuscule* et la *nuit* il est plus perceptible et plus long l'été.

Comment: J'ai écouté cette chanson tellement de fois sans saisir ce passage... merci !

Answer (score 3):

L'heure bleu est le moment après que le soleil passe  l'horizon, quand le ciel est encore bleu foncé, avant de devenir noir. C'est en fait l'équivalent de l'aube au soir.

Answer (score 2):

« [*Vespéral*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/vesp%C3%A9ral) » est surtout un adjectif littéraire signifiant *du soir/du couchant*. On peut parler d' « *oraison/heure ou de lumière vespérale* » par exemple; et le substantif réfère particulièrement au livre de prières étant associé à ce moment particulier dans certaines traditions liturgiques. D'ailleurs les mots [*vêpres*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/v%C3%AApres) (f, p), *vêpre* (m, s) et *vêprée* (rég.) correspondent à ce moment précis dans un tel contexte, ou généralement à l'après-midi ou au soir. Le « (moment de l'oraison) vespéral(e) » serait annoncé par le « [rayon](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/rayon) vert », ce « *[b]ref éclat de couleur verte observable dans certaines conditions au lever et au coucher du soleil, dû à l'absorption des rayons solaires par l'atmosphère.* » (TLFi) qui rappellerait en corolaire l'embrasement de l'[aurore](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/aurore) et de sa [déesse](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aurore_%28mythologie%29). On retrouverait ainsi : *aube-aurore-jour, vespéral-crépuscule-nuit*.

Answer (score 1):

L'aube est le moment où le ciel redevient assez clair pour que l'on puisse distinguer à nouveau les couleurs.

L'aurore est un embrasement passager (étymologiquement, bien qu'Homère parle de la déesse Aurore aux doigts de rose - l'image est remarquablement exacte en Grèce, hors des villes polluées), dû au passage rasant des rayons du soleil dans l'atmosphère.

Au couchant, le même phénomène se produit ; le terme "ustion" aurait été adéquat, mais aucun auteur ne l'a retenu en ce sens.

Enfin, au crépuscule, on distingue de moins en moins les couleurs et tous les chats sont gris.

Answer (score 1):

La "brunante" ou "brune".
On dit : rendez-vous à la brunante.
C'est juste avant le crépuscule pour le soir; exactement à l'inverse de l'aurore pour le matin.

Comment: À noter que les dictionnaires que j'ai consultés le donne comme propre au Canada,