# "Au coucher" ou "au couchant"?

Tags: choix-de-mot, différence

Quelqu'un vient de me demander si l'expression "au coucher" ou "au couchant" (il ne se rappelle pas ce qu'il a entendu) peut exister toute seule, sans "soleil". J'ai instinctivement dit oui, mais quand j'ai voulu vérifier si c'est l'un ou l'autre, je n'ai pas réussi à comprendre la différence.

Est-ce qu'on peut dire le deux sans différence de sens?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

« Au couchant » peut vouloir dire « au coucher du soleil ». De manière générale, « le couchant » sans précision est une manière relativement rare de dire « le coucher du soleil ». Le [TLF](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/couchant) (II.B) cite quelques exemples.

« Au coucher » sans précision peut être le moment où n'importe quoi ou n'importe qui se couche. Si l'expression n'est pas qualifiée, je pense au moment où quelqu'un se couche.

Answer (score 3):

***Au couchant*** indique d'abord une direction à l'horizon, l'ouest, indépendamment de l'heure de la journée. Le **couchant** (là où le soleil se couche), parfois appelé aussi **ponant**, s'oppose au **levant** (l'est, là où le soleil se lève).

***Au coucher*** indique le moment de la soirée où on se couche.

> Certains jours, des nocturnes permettent d’assister au coucher des lions, des girafes et des singes. ([Abritel](https://www.abritel.fr/guides-voyage/famille/guide-destinations-famille/lle-de-france/sortie-enfant-paris))

> Prendre un comprimé au coucher, pendant un mois. ([Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43889756/mozilla-does-not-interpret-the-html-contained-in-my-xml))

Ce coucher a bien sûr un lien avec celui du soleil, mais il est rarement synchrone avec lui.

Avec Soleil, on parlera le plus souvent de ***coucher de soleil*** ou de ***soleil couchant***, très très rarement de *couchant de soleil*. Je n'ai jamais entendu quelqu'un désigner le coucher de soleil par le substantif *couchant* mais on en trouve quelques exemples dans la littérature et même dans [une réponse sur FSE](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/7432/1109).

Comment: Not sure that StackOverflow is the best place to get a quote from ;-)

Comment: @Kaiido Most of the hits returned by the search engines were from pharmaceutical companies except for that unexpected one from stack overflow. I thought it would be funny to pick it. ;-)